# D3 JS - How to convert a grid of svgs as one to increase the overall performance?

Tags: performance, d3.js, svg

Currently I am constructing a mosaic like grids svg with D3JS.

You can imagine as the following image.

I have labeled the small images, and having the data as a 2D array of labels to map the small images as an final mosaic image like this. The problem I have is I will have multiple mosaic images and some time more than 30 images on a page with different grid sizes. Since each mosaic images are actually a node from a d3 tree with relationships. The performance decrease as more nodes and svgs are presented.

Is there any alternative ways to convert the grid of svgs on the fly? Or is there other better suggestions to achieve the same result in D3js?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Maybe find a way to render each mosaic as canvas, so the browser would have to support less elements?

Comment: Thanks @ValentinLevalet for your suggestion. But one tricky part is each mosaic is appended to the node of the tree, I am having a hard time of figuring out how to just convert the mosaic into a canvas / img then when mouse over the tree node, the mosaic will still show (scale up and enlarge from the node in my case)